# How to add new dimension in tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, dataloader

I currently have following tensor with dimensions `[batch_size, channel, width, height]` but I want to add one dimension to the above tensors at third index as `[batch_size, channel, length, width, height]` where length is the dimension that I want to add into my tensor. Length value will be defined as the `no_of_iterations` for batch size. Can you please tell me how should I add need dimension and set its value.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims, this may help

Comment: Is this a PyTorch or a TensorFlow question ? In PyTorch, It's quite easy to do. In TensorFlow, I'm no expert, but I think it's a much harder task to perform this dynamically.

Comment: Please, be more specific w.r.t. the framework of interest and avoid using irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

You could not modify your batch dynamically like that. You can hand on with static tensor only. Therefore, you have to make your tensor static at first. Then, you can accumulate the dimension by using `tf.expand_dims` and choose the axis that you want to expand. Here is 2 as the axis for length.

However, expand_dims just have you to create a dimension. Then you have to duplicate the tensor and `tf.concatenate` the tensor by axis=2.

However, I want to give you some suggestion, I think you just need to add a loop for each batch training that you want to do inside each epoch. That will be easier and handy than modify tensor like this and reduce the complexity for high dimensions